# Stability of the zero solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Consider the equations:
>   $$z_1'=z_2 - t z_2^3,~~~~z_2'=-\frac{1}{2}z_2^3.$$
>   **Question.** Comment on the stability of the zero solution.

Here the matrix associated with the linear part of the equation is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which has two zero eigen values. Hence the zero solution is unstable. Since the stability of the linear solution is same as the stability of the nonlinear solution, if suffices to comment about the stability of the linear solution.  Do I have to justify more ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Since the stability of the linear solution is same as the stability of the nonlinear solution." This is in general not correct. Without further investigation we can only state this for hyperbolic equilibrium points by theorem of Grobman-Hartman. But here you have an non-hyperbolic one since the eigenvalues are zero. There are other ways though, for example constructing a Lyapunov function or just looking what your system is doing in a neighborhood of zero.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't heard of that theorem. So my argument is invalid ? I can just find the solutions for the two ODEs then and comment on their behavior when $t \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Just saying it is stable is not valid. Loosely speaking Grobman-Hartman says the following: For a hyperbolic equilibrium the system behaves locally around the equilibrium like the linear system. Yes the second method is absolutely fine; investigating the behavior of the flow map directly.